# In bash, how can I remove multiple versions of the same file?

Tags: bash, automation, scripting

This may be a very specific case, but I know very little about bash and I need to remove "duplicate" files. I've been downloading totally legal videogame roms these past few days, and I noticed that a lot of packs have many different versions of the same game, like this:

```
Awesome Golf (1991).lnx
Awesome Golf (1991) [b1].lnx
Baseball Heroes (1991).lnx
Baseball Heroes (1991) [b1].lnx
Basketbrawl (1992).lnx
Basketbrawl (1992) [a1].lnx
Basketbrawl (1992) [b1].lnx
Batman Returns (1992).lnx
Batman Returns (1992) [b1].lnx
```

How can I make a bash script that removes the duplicates? A duplicate would be any file that has the same name, and the name would be the string before the first parenthesis. The script should parse all the files and grab their names, see which names match to detect duplicates, and remove all files except the first one (first being the first that comes up in alphabetical order).

Comment: Which ones are duplicates? Those with `[a1]`, `[b1]`, etc?

Comment: Those with the same name. The idea would be to treat as duplicate everything that has the same name (i.e, everything before the parenthesis) and remove everything except the first one.

Comment: you state *"keep only the first one"* ... but ... which one is the **first one**?  is **'first'** determined by the download datetime stamp? is **'first'** determined by the (non) existence of a set of parens, or brackets? you need to provide a textual description of how you determine which file is **'first'**

Comment: Alphabetical order.

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks but I don't see how I can apply this to achieve what I want. That only searches files for a specific pattern, I would need to make the pattern on the fly (that's be the name), match everything that has it, sort alphabetically and remove everything except the first one.

Comment: update the question with these additional details (not everyone is going to read through the comments trying to piece together the whole picture); also ... for the given sample input ... update the question with **a)** what you've tried so far, **b)** the (wrong) results your code generates and **c)** the (correct) desired output; one other thing, replace the image with a text/code block of the actual filenames ... something we can (easily) cut-n-paste into test cases (ie, we're not interested in spending our time converting images to text)

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso I'll update the question as asked.

Comment: @Quasímodo In this particular example, yes that would do, but I have other lists that contain repeated roms without brackets (they have differences stated in parenthesis, but I can't remove things with parenthesis because they have their years displayed there, so I'd be left with nothing).

Comment: You might be better of getting the MD5 digests (checksums) of all your files then looking for duplicates (by piping through `sort` and `uniq -d`) then deleting the duplicates with the longest names.

Comment: Learn to use [git](https://git-scm.com/) it would be useful next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="dir"                               # the directory where the rom files are located
declare -A seen                         # associative array to detect the duplicates
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do          # loop over filenames by assigning "f" to it
    name=${f%(*}                        # extract the "name" by removing left paren and following characters
    name=${name%.*}                     # remove the extension considering the case the filename doesn't have parens
    name=${name%[*}                     # remove the left square bracket and following characters considering the case as above
    name=${name%% }                     # remove trailing whitespaces, if any
    if (( seen[$name]++ )); then        # if the name duplicates...
        # remove "echo" if the output looks good
        echo rm -- "$f"                 # then remove the file
    fi
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -name "*.lnx" -print0 | sort -z -t "." -k1,1)
                                        # sort the list of filenames in alphabetical order
```

- Please modify the first `dir=` line to your directory path which holds the rom files.
- The `echo` command just prints the filenames to be removed as a rehearsal. If the output looks good, then remove `echo` and execute the real one.

**[Explanation]**

- An associative array `seen` associates the extracted "name" with a
  counter of appearance. If the counter is non-zero, the file is a duplicated
  one and can be removed (as long as the files are properly sorted).
- The `-print0` option to `find`, the `-z` option to `sort` and the `-d ""`
  option to `read` make a null character as a delimiter of filenames to
  accept filenames which contain special characters such as a whitespace,
  tab, newline, etc.

Comment: This works perfectly! It throws some "bad array subscript" errors but it does delete everything it needs to, so great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The "bad array subscript" error may occur if the
key to the associative array is empty. It is an unexpected behavior, but
if the final results meet your requirements, it will be okay. If you want to fix the error, please let me know.

Comment: Well I did notice that if the file doesn't have a parenthesis then it will never match, because the extension is present. Let's say we have `Game1 (b1).ext` and `Game1.ext`, the script would remove everything after the parenthesis in the first example, but it would leave the second string intact with the extension, so when it compares both of them it won't match and they won't get deleted. The script did help me tons already, but if you know how to work around that I'd appreciate it. As I said I know basically no bash sadly.

Comment: May I assume the extension is always `.lnx`?

Comment: Let me confirm. Is the said filename `Game1 (b1).lnx`, not `Game1 [b1].lnx`?

Comment: I removed the extension check since I have multiple rom lists with different extensions, the extension doesn't matter. Also, having brackets or parenthesis doesn't matter either, I can just change that in a whim if needed, and it's mostly parenthesis anyway, the problem is when there's nothing at all so the script doesn't remove the extension and the strings don't match.

Comment: All right. I have updated the script in my answer. I've added two lines: one to remove extension, one to remove square bracket. Now it will work if the filename does not contain parens.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot man, appreciate it.